# How to trigger a graphql query when a ref changes with the vue composition api?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, graphql, vue-component

With the [graphql Vue code generator](https://graphql-code-generator.com/docs/plugins/typescript-vue-apollo) we created the following working query that returns the app preferences:

```js
const { result, loading, error } = useViewerQuery()
const preference = useResult(result, null, (data) => data.viewer.preference)
```

We would like to fetch the preferences only once just after a user is authenticated in the `MainLayout.vue` component, so we can use a spinner based on the `loading` ref before we can render the full UI in the correct user language (which comes from the preferences).

The issue we have is to trigger the `userViewerQuery` only when the ref `isAuthenticated` is set to `true` in the `MainLayout.vue` setup function. We can't seem to expose the `loading` and `error` refs when they are within the `watchEffect` function.

```js
// MainLayout.vue
<script>
import { defineComponent, watchEffect } from '@vue/composition-api'
import { isAuthenticated } from 'src/store/authStore'
import { useViewerQuery } from 'src/graphql/generated/operations'

export default defineComponent({
  setup(_, { root }) {
    watchEffect(() => {
      if (isAuthenticated.value === true) {
        const { result, loading, error } = useViewerQuery()
      }
    })

    return {
      isAuthenticated,
      loading,
      error,
    }
  },
})
</script>
```

Then later on we would simply like to use the preferences retrieved in the `Settings.vue` component. Because they are already fetched the data for preferences should be cached and readily available:

```js
// Settings.vue
const { result } = useViewerQuery()
const preference = useResult(result, null, (data) => data.viewer.preference)
```

Maybe we're approaching this the wrong way. Any help or advise is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to [this tip](https://spectrum.chat/apollo/react-apollo/conditionally-query-if-a-variable-exists%7E684a6e71-2452-4f51-97ae-57b4bf3ebdf6). When using `useQuery` with Vue Apollo there is [an option](https://v4.apollo.vuejs.org/guide-composable/query.html#options) called `enabled` that defines if a query is run or not.

**From the docs:**

```js
const enabled = ref(false)

const { result } = useQuery(gql`
  ...
`, null, () => ({
  enabled: enabled.value,
}))

function enableQuery () {
  enabled.value = true
}
```

Applying this logic to my own situation, where I only want the query to run when the user is logged in and the ref `isAuthenticated` is set to `true`:

```js
export default defineComponent({
  setup(_, { root }) {
    const { result, loading, error } = useViewerQuery(() => ({
      enabled: isAuthenticated.value,
    }))

    watchEffect(() => {
      console.log('MainLayout isAuthenticated: ', isAuthenticated.value)
    })
    watchEffect(() => {
      console.log('MainLayout result: ', result.value)
    })

    return {
      isAuthenticated,
      loading,
      error,
    }
  },
```

I hope this helps others with a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could scope up the refs and add a property that calls the gql endpoint. Something like...

```js
export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const { result, loading, error, call } = useViewerQuery()
    watchEffect(async () => {
      if (isAuthenticated.value) {
          await call()
      }
    })

    return {
      isAuthenticated,
      loading,
      error
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but the `useViewerQuery()` is always executed and doesn't return a function to be used as caller. `useMutaton` has [this functionality](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/) with the `mutate` funciton but `useQuery` [does not](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/).